# VBS Broken If Statement/Logic

Tags: if-statement, vbscript, registry, operators, logic

My logic/code is pretty simple count rows from a SQL table, store this value to a Registry Key. If the value read from the SQL query is greater than the value of the RegKey, update the value of the RegKey with the query result, and likewise, save the value to a log file. If, the value of the SQL query is equal to the RegKey value, then do not store the result to the RegKey, but write 0 to the log file.

I run this code, and it seems it does not like my IF statements/operators. Testing this, it only seems to work if I set the operation "tempSQLCount(0,0) < strRegKeyVal " or "tempSQLCount(0,0) <> strRegKeyVal". In my scenario, the SQLCounter will never be less than, only greater than, or equal.

```
    strRegKeyVal = readfromRegistry("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SQLCounter1", "ha")
'Dim intRegKeyVal = CInt(strRegKeyVal)

If tempSQLCount(0,0) > strRegKeyVal Then
    'update row counter value to regKey 
    strValueName = "SQLCounter1"
    objRegistry.CreateKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath
    objRegistry.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,tempSQLCount(0,0)

    Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'write to log
    outFile="C:\Logs\some.log"
    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
    objFile.Write tempSQLCount(0,0) & vbCrLf
    objFile.Close
End If
If tempSQLCount(0,0) = strRegKeyVal Then
    'update row counter value to regKey 

    Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'write to log
    outFile="C:\Logs\some.log"
    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
    objFile.Write 0 & vbCrLf
    objFile.Close
End If
```

Comment: What is the output of `WScript.Echo tempSQLCount(0,0) & " (" & TypeName(tempSQLCount(0,0)) & ")"` and `WScript.Echo strRegKeyVal & " (" & TypeName(strRegKeyVal) & ")"`?

Comment: I suspect you're unintentionally comparing strings when you want to compare numbers - so what you're doing is getting alphabetical order.  In this situation "9" > "10"; That CINT() might be important.  Also, consider storing the result of tempSQLCount in a variable too.  The way it's written right now, you may be calling your DB several times - this is not only bad from a performance perspective but you also could get a different result each time!  Lastly, consider an ElseIf instead of a separate If block.  As currently written both If blocks could run under certain circumstances.

Comment: I would write the comparing variables to log: Make the `Set objFSO` above the IF blocks, then `objFile.WriteLine "tempSQLCount(0,0) = " & tempSQLCount(0,0) & " [" & TypeName(tempSQLCount(0,0)) & "]"`, and `objFile.WriteLine "strRegKeyVal = " & strRegKeyVal & " [" & TypeName(strRegKeyVal)) & "]"`. Close the file below the If blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Get your logic straight and convert your numbers to the correct type. (This is mostly what the commenters suggested, but comments are hard to read for code improvements):

```
dim strRegKeyVal, sqlCountToReport, sqlCount

' both values are converted to Int
strRegKeyVal = cInt(readfromRegistry("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SQLCounter1", "ha"))
sqlCount = cInt(tempSQLCount(0,0))

' Conditional registry write part
If sqlCount > strRegKeyVal Then
    'update row counter value to regKey 
    strValueName = "SQLCounter1"
    objRegistry.CreateKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath
    objRegistry.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName, sqlCount
    sqlCountToReport = sqlCount
else
    sqlCountToReport = 0    
End If

' Write to log part
Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Logs\some.log", True)
objFile.Write sqlCountToReport & vbCrLf
objFile.Close
```

Your script consist of two parts: the registry update part and the log write part. Splitting it in two tasks is easier to debug. 
The flow is a little bit different; this also covers the case if `cInt(tempSQLCount(0,0)) < strRegKeyVal`, but that was a case that shouldn't happen anyways.

Comment: thanks for consolidating.

interesting.. works fine in dev., but in production it does not.

I narrowed my issue down to the fact it does not like the CINT() functions..